# background service lost gps location listener stalls

Tags: android, service, gps, location

I have a background service to toast lost GPS signal and measure distance (on the timer as there is a lot of slow moving! back and forth and turns for this application yet doesn't measure every location change as the main app draws enough resources) 
 This service will not die if the main app gets killed due to ph calls etc. and user has to reenter app and exit to kill it and yes it won't die unless stoptimer=true

Hopefully useful to others with cleaning up

Note.
prefs to control
stoptimer=true        to stop service
startmeasure=true     to measure distance

Write( context, allinediss, alllines);      read this pref get distance in main app using  public static String Read(Context context, final String key)

This is a smaller version of add on for my first app so could probably be much improved by someone who knows what they are doing and my debugging needs improvement.

ps getdistance was for rhumb distance and did not work so fix it or clean it and I don't know the error factor of adding multiple small great circle distances (if there is one)

String adis=Read(context,allinediss);

Was empty and throwing number format exception so added this to fix it.
     if(adis.length()<1){adis="0";
             }

```
     public class Timer extends Service implements      LocationListener {
public Timer() {
}
    LocationManager locationManager ;


    double lon;
    double lat;

   Handler handler = new Handler();
 double starmeasure=2;
 double  measurecounter=0;
double alllinedis;
 double lat2;
 double lon2;
 double lat1;
 double lon1;
 double latfs;
 double lonfs;
  double time=1;
  double time1=1;
  int timercount=0;
String allinediss="allines";

DecimalFormat precision00 = new                   DecimalFormat("0.00");



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "H service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);        

      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String timerb="timerb";
    boolean stoptimer=ReadBoolean(context,timerb,false);

if(stoptimer==false){

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);




}   



}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here...
      Toast.makeText(this, "service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "meter service destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}



   /*
//First we need a Handler that starts the Runnable after 100ms

private Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

*/

//And we also need the Runnable for the Handler

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      /* do what you need to do */


       gpstime();

      // savpointforroute();

       Context context = getApplicationContext();
       String timerb="timerb";
       boolean       stoptimer=ReadBoolean(context,timerb,false);
/* and here comes the "trick" */
       if(stoptimer==false){
      handler.postDelayed(this, 1000*20);
 }



 }   };



public void startmeasure() {

    //This will check if null and reset measure to get 2 fixes before adding distance on
    String lats=Double.toString(lat);
    if (lats.length() < 4){    

    Toast.makeText(this,"lats null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    starmeasure=2;

    return;

}

       //       Toast.makeText(this,  "timerlat"+lats, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



//pref to turn on  or off measure NOT reset
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
     String startmeasure="startmeasure";
    boolean startmeasureb=ReadBoolean( context, startmeasure, true);

if(startmeasureb==true){
     starmeasure=starmeasure+1;
//4 fixes before measure started    
if(starmeasure>4){

    if (measurecounter>1){
          lat1=lat;
          lon1=lon;
     //    double linedist=getRhumbLineDistance(lat2,lon2,lat,lon);

         //old lat to measure too
         Location apoint2=new Location("");

         apoint2.setLatitude(lat2);
         apoint2.setLongitude(lon2);




         //set latlng location to measure to
         Location tpoint2=new Location("");

         tpoint2.setLatitude(lat);
         tpoint2.setLongitude(lon);

    //   double linedist=getDistance( lat,  lon, lat2,  lon2) ;



            double linedist=apoint2.distanceTo(tpoint2);

        //failsafe exceed distance back to zero 
        if(linedist>200){
            linedist=0;
        }   


         String adis=Read(context,allinediss);
                     if(adis.length()<1){adis="0";
         }


         alllinedis=Double.parseDouble(adis); 


             double a=alllinedis+linedist;

         alllinedis=a;

         alllinedis=Math.round(alllinedis);

         measurecounter=0;




     }else{
        measurecounter=2; 

             lat2=lat;
         lon2=lon;
       // double linedist=getRhumbLineDistance(lat1,lon1,lat,lon);


         Location nt=new Location("");

          nt.setLatitude(lat1);
          nt.setLongitude(lon1);




         //set latlng location target to get dis to line

             Location oint=new Location("");

         oint.setLatitude(lat);
         oint.setLongitude(lon);


    //   double linedist=getDistance( lat,  lon, lat1,  lon1) ;

            double linedist=nt.distanceTo(oint);






         if(linedist>200){
         linedist=0;
         }


         // add measured to original distance
       String adis=Read(context,allinediss);
             if(adis.length()<1){adis="0";
         }


                 alllinedis=Double.parseDouble(adis); 

            double b=alllinedis+linedist;

             alllinedis=b;   

        //   alllinedis=alllinedis+linedist;


                 alllinedis=Math.round(alllinedis);

    //   Toast.makeText(this,"dis"+Double.toString( alllinedis), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    }



         //Distance covered to pref
         String alllines=Double.toString(alllinedis);
         String allinediss="allines";
        Write( context, allinediss, alllines);
     }  
    }
    }

    private void gpstime(){



if(  time1==time ){

    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS Signal Lost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    startmeasure();
}
time1=time;
        /*  String time1s=Double.toString(time);
Toast.makeText(this, time1s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     */

}








// String
    public static String Read(Context context, final String key) {
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return pref.getString(key, "");
}



       public static void Write(Context context, final          String key, final String value) {
       SharedPreferences settings =      PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();        
   }



   // Boolean  
               public static boolean ReadBoolean(Context context, final String key, final boolean defaultValue) {
         SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
return settings.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
 }



        public static void WriteBoolean(Context context, final String key, final boolean value) {
SharedPreferences settings =      PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean(key, value);
editor.commit();        
  }





     public double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) 
    { 
double latA = Math.toRadians(lat1); 
double lonA = Math.toRadians(lon1);
double latB = Math.toRadians(lat2); 
double lonB = Math.toRadians(lon2); 
double cosAng = (Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonB-lonA)) + (Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB)); 
double ang = Math.acos(cosAng); 
double dist = ang *6371; 
return dist;

 }

 //@Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    lat =(location.getLatitude());

             lon =(location.getLongitude());
time=(location.getTime());

  //     Toast.makeText(this, "loc changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



   //    startmeasure();



}

  @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: heh, Could you make the code more unreadable, please? You can add more "\n" between lines, f* all indents - not only few. Or even better, minify the source and then post it here...

Comment: Posted it off a phone. Its messier than I thought. I think minify will loose the problem code as maybe it has to do with repeatable runner? I will take a heap of test toasts etc out.

Answer (score 0):

String adis=Read(context,allinediss);

Was empty and throwing number format exception so added this to fix it.

if(adis.length()<1){adis="0"; }

edited question so it works